# long and float fields showing up as text fields in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

Running Kibana version 5.5.2.
My current setup is Logstash is taking the logs from Docker containers, runs grok filters before sending the logs to elasticsearch. The specific logs that I need to show up as long, float are two times from AWS calls to ECS and EC2 and currently a grok filter pulls them out. Here is the custom filter that pulls out the ECS timings: `ECS_DESCRIBE_CONTAINER_INSTANCES (AWS)(%{SPACE})(ecs)(%{SPACE})(%{POSINT})(%{SPACE})(?<ECS_DURATION>(%{NUMBER}))(s)(%{SPACE})(?<ECS_RETRIES>(%{NONNEGINT}))(%{SPACE})(retries)` so I need ECS_DURATION to be a float and ECS_RETRIES to be a long. In the docker log handler I have the following

```
    if [ECS_DURATION] {
      mutate {
        convert => ["ECS_DURATION", "float"]
      }
    }

    if [ECS_RETRIES] {
      mutate {
        convert => ["ECS_RETRIES", "integer"]
      }
    }
```

When I look at the field in Kibana, it still shows as a text field, but when I make the following request to elasticsearch for the mappings, it shows those fields as long and float.

```
GET /logstash-2020.12.18/_mapping
{
  "logstash-2020.12.18": {
    "mappings": {
      "log": {
        "_all": {
          "enabled": true,
          "norms": false
        },
        "dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "message_field": {
              "path_match": "message",
              "match_mapping_type": "string",
              "mapping": {
                "norms": false,
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "string_fields": {
              "match": "*",
              "match_mapping_type": "string",
              "mapping": {
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "ignore_above": 256,
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                },
                "norms": false,
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "include_in_all": false
          },
          "@version": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "include_in_all": false
          },
          "EC2_DURATION": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "EC2_RETRIES": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "ECS_DURATION": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "ECS_RETRIES": {
            "type": "long"
          },
```

I even created a custom mapping template in elasticsearch with the following call

```
PUT /_template/aws_durations?pretty
{
  "template": "logstash*",
  "mappings": {
    "type1": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "ECS_DURATION": {
          "type": "half_float"
        },
        "ECS_RETRIES": {
          "type": "byte"
        },
        "EC2_DURATION": {
          "type": "half_float"
        },
        "EC2_RETRIES": {
          "type": "byte"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's been some time since I had worked on something like this, but have you tried to [reload the data fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.10/index-patterns.html#_refresh_the_data_fields) in Kibana? If the fields you want were previously string fields, Kibana might have updated the mapping automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that its actually going into the  `if [ECS_DURATION]` and `if [ECS_RETRIES]` conditions? (I wasnt able to comment)

Comment: Yes because when I change those fields to something else, the mapping also changes. I initially tried making them byte and half_float and it was failing and then I read somewhere that you can't convert to those. So as I change the convert in those sections I see it reflected in the logstash mapping